# Phaser 3 low image quality after resize

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Phaser 3 (version. 3.20.1) I can't find a way to not lose quality when I resize my images.
I tried different variants: setDisplaySize or setScale on image and setZoom on camera, but image still look pixelated.

In game config I changed  "type" to WebGl/Canvas, sets to render object params: antialias, pixelArt, roundPixels.

My game config:

```
{
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    disableContextMenu: true,
    banner: false,
    scale: {
        height,
        width,
        parent: 'canvas',
        mode: Phaser.Scale.NONE,
        autoRound: true,
    },
    render: {
        roundPixels: true,
    },
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKarF.png)

1. resize image in html
2. resize image by setScale
3. setZoom on camera

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another solution, for mobile I resize canvas instead of change camera zoom:

```
this.scene.scale.parent.width = Math.round(width);
this.scene.scale.parent.height = Math.round(height);

this.scene.scale.canvas.style.width = Math.round(width) + 'px';
this.scene.scale.canvas.style.height = Math.round(height) + 'px';
game.canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
game.canvas.style.height = height + 'px';
```

I spent almost a week on this solution, I hope someone will help

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution because it implies to go back to 3.15 version.

In this version you can change the resolution in the config like so :

```
var config = {
...
resolution: 3, // the higher the better (but certainly slower)
...
}
```